# What is the best way to update a known row in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

For example, if I want to frequently update a user's score during a session,
is there a more performant way than - UPDATE score FROM [databaseName] WHERE name = [username]

I feel like I should not be continuously needing to search through the entire database when the value's location has been previously found.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such thing as *the value's location* in sql.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't search through the entire database if you had an index on `name`:

```
create index idx_<table>_name on <table>(name);
```

where `<table>` is the name of the **table** you are referring to, not the database.

Incidentally, if you wanted to update the table, you would use `update`, not `select`.  But `update` can still use the index.

Comment: Wow you're fast! Thanks so much, I'll try that out. Just came back to edit that "Select" error in my question, but you got here too quick :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties here you can search and update only the database when you need it.

```
private int score;
        public int Score
        {
            get
            {
                score = searchDatabase();
                return score;
            }
            set
            {
                UpdateDatabase(value);
                score = value;
            }
        }
    
    
    Debug.Log(Score);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still requires that I search the entire database each time I need to update the score right?

Comment: search in table instead of database. If you want you can only update the score if gameover and top score like that and not every time when the score is changing.

Comment: Thanks, yes I had thought of something similar. But I'm actually required to constantly update in the DB for a test. Suppose you can consider it in the context of a multiplayer game

Comment: well you can make a delegate to listen to other player if there score update and that moment you grab there score and not every frame thats expensive.

Comment: or you can make a gamemanager thats update score then make your player client delegate to subscribe to that event.

Comment: or make your server send updated score to everyone if one has update there score.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind that resembles what you mention as the *value's location*, is the value of the primary key column of the row with the value that you search for.
So, if the primary key in the table is `id` and you only have the `name` of the person, you can query once to get the row's `id`:

```
SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE name = ?
```

and then use that `id` in all subsequent updates:

```
UPDATE tablename SET score = ? WHERE id = ?
```

This is the fastest way to do the updates.